# How to handle configuration properties in Java

Tags: java, parsing

For the purpose of my project I need to have a Config file to set some values and I need to parse this file and extract assigned values to my variables in the code. Do you have any suggestion or any tool I could use? and I'm coding with Java!

Comment: What format is the config file? [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Leverage standard Java [`Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class. Create a properties file, i.e. `conf.properties` and load it.

```
#conf.properties:
key=value

#code
Properties conf = new Properties();
conf.load(new FileInputStream(new File("conf.properties")));
conf.getProperty("key"); // returns "value"
```

Answer (score 3):

Java has a standard for this, it's called [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html).

Answer (score 2):

You doesn't need any tool for this simple project. Store the values as name=value pairs making sure they adhere to the java.util.Properties format and then you can use the class's API to load them

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method is to use a text file. It is advisable to put variables with their values ​​in an xml file and then read it with Sax. Another method is to use json.